# the characters except 0x00-0x7F are not been shown when converted to "UTF-8" from "ISO-8859-1"

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding

I need to get a string from URL request of brower, and then create a text image by requested text. I know the default encoding of the Java net transmission is "ISO-8859-1", it can works normally with all characters what defined in "ISO-8859-1". But when I request a multi-byte Unicode character (e.g. chinese or something like `¤ж`), then I need to decode it by "UTF-8" from "ISO-8859-1".

My codes like:

```
String reslut = new String(requestString.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
```

Everything is fine, but I found some characters in ISO-8859-1 are not been shown now, which characters are 0x80 - 0xFF(defined in" ISO-8859-1"), i.e. the characters except 0x00-0x7F are not been shown when converted to "UTF-8" from "ISO-8859-1"

Any other method can solve this query?

Comment: There are no characters after 0x80 in ASCII. ASCII only specifies characters up to 127. Perhaps you are thinking of something else?

Comment: yeah, after 0x80 in ASCII are defined by "ISO-8859-1"

Comment: @user293018: you're confused as to what the definition of ASCII and ISO-Latin-1/ISO-8859-1 are.  I think your question would make more sense if you were to replace all the 'ASCII' you wrote by 'ISO-8859-1' (and even then it would still be weirdly formulated), because as of now neither your question nor your comment make any sense.

Comment: @Mike.Huang: No, that’s not correct. ISO 8859-1 is just one character set that’s characters from 0 to 128 are identical to ASCII’s character set. But there are many others (e.g. the Unicode character set or all other character sets in ISO 8859).

Comment: Yeah, my query is the characters except 0x00-0x7F are not been shown when converted to "UTF-8" from "ISO-8859-1".

Comment: Shown where ? Does whatever device you show them on know the encoding is UTF-8 ?

Answer (score 3):

> I know the default encoding of the Java net transmission is "ISO-8859-1"

I am not sure what you mean here, but this is not true in networking. All goes in **bytes** over the line. Maybe you're confusing it with the default encoding of the `InputStreamReader` with which you attempt to read the byte stream as characters. When constructing an `InputStreamReader` for a byte stream, you should use [the constructor which takes the encoding as 2nd argument](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String%29). E.g.

```
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
```

If you're actually using `java.net.URLConnection`, then you should first filter the encoding from the `Content-Type` [header](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getHeaderField%28java.lang.String%29) and apply it as encoding.

Comment: the question is after encoded with "utf-8", the characters 0x80-0xFF(in ISO-8859-1) are not been shown.

Comment: Then likely either the original stream was not in UTF-8, or you're **writing** the characters using a wrong encoding (to a file, or to the console, or to a webpage, etc where you're viewing them). You need to ensure that it is also using the same and correct encoding. Try posting a sample string and both the expected and unexpected output.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do doesn't really make sense. Most ISO-8859-1 strings cannot be interpreted as UTF-8 strings.

Additionally, Chinese characters are not encodable in ISO-8859-1 (ISO-8859-1 is designed for Western European languages).

Comment: Everything is fine, include Chinese and other multi-byte Unicode character, except 0x80-0xFF(in "ISO-8859-1").

Your addition is right, but the multi-byte Unicode character are transfered by "ISO-8859-1", you can convert it by "UTF-8" as well, because browser is using "UTF-8" to encode the multi-byte Unicode .